# Who first said, "If you think floating point is the answer, you don't understand the problem."

Tags: floating-point

I had a C (programming language) teacher at the Lowell Institute at MIT who said this in the Spring of 1996.  It's an overstatement, but still seems like a classic quote to me.  I've had no luck searching for attribution over the years.

I don't want to debate the usefulness of IEEE floating point.  It is useful and I use it.  The quote reminds me to be mindful of its quirks and limits.  I'm just looking for attribution for the quote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about quote attribution, not software engineering.

Comment: ["If you think you need floating point to solve the problem, you don't understand the problem"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22If%20you%20think%20you%20need%20floating%20point%20to%20solve%20the%20problem%2C%20you%20don%27t%20understand%20the%20problem%22&*&rct=j), which leads to [this post](http://forums.parallax.com/discussion/comment/1398989/#Comment_1398989).  The almighty Internet doesn't yield any further information.